# CarbonKit - Refresh/Reload tab view

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm using carbonkit in my project. As the tabs only takes text/image as views, I rendered text into image and placed it on the tabs.

```
- (UIImage*) generateImageWithText:(UIImage*)img text:(NSString*)text
{
    UIImageView *view = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 80, 80)];

    UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:img];
    imgView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    imgView.frame = CGRectMake(15, 15, view.bounds.size.width-30, view.bounds.size.height-50);
    imgView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

    UILabel *lbl = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, imgView.frame.size.height + 20, view.bounds.size.width, 30)];
    lbl.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    lbl.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    lbl.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    lbl.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
    lbl.text = text;
    lbl.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    lbl.numberOfLines = 2;
    [view addSubview:imgView];
    [view addSubview:lbl];

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, NO, 0);
    [view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

    UIImage *imageWithText = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return imageWithText;
}
```

I need to reload/refresh tab view (not tab page controllers) on tap of a button. But the tabs are overlapped (new tabs over previous). How can i solve this issue?
[image][image]

Answer (score 0):

First you need to remove the text and image from the view and create new image and label.

Comment: there is no way to remove previous images from the toolBar. CarbonKit uses `[[CarbonTabSwipeNavigation alloc] initWithItems:items toolBar:self.toolBar delegate:self]` and 
        `[carbonTabSwipeNavigation insertIntoRootViewController:self andTargetView:self.targetView];` to set views

Comment: while reload or refreshing the tabview, call this initWithItems method, at that time remove the previously created object.

Comment: i can not send nil items to `[[CarbonTabSwipeNavigation alloc] initWithItems:items toolBar:self.toolBar delegate:self]` it required nonnull object, so it crashes. i tried to pass items array with nil image and `@""` text (inside `generatingImageWithText`), but it did nothing.

Comment: while creating the tabbar (first time) you will send some images in that items right, send the same while refreshing too.